# Save array into xls file

Tags: php, phpexcel

I wish to save my 2 dimensional array into an .xls file.  If use this code, the data is saved without leading zeroes:

```
$arr = array(
    array("01", "02", "03"),
    array("001", "02", "03"),
    array("00001", "02", "03"),
);


// include PHPExcel library

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($arr);
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save("file.xls");
```

If use this instead, `01` is saved as `00001`:

```
......
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($arr);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:C3')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode("00000");
.....
```

How can I solve this problem? How can I save the original data from my array into an .xls file correctly?

Comment: Would it be viable to `strlen()` the element and then use `str_repeat()` to set the format?

Comment: @ SmokeyPHP  --- You mean that make this in cycle? for each element to array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the cells to the *text* format instead:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:C3')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('@');
```

or loop through the array, setting the format according to the string's length (`->setFormatCode(str_repeat('0', strlen($arrElem));`, but that would be as silly as looping over the array, and explicitly setting each value:

```
$objPHPExcel->->getCell('A1')->setValueExplicit($arr[0][0], PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
```

There might be a case for the blunt approach here, too:

```
$objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()
            ->getNumberFormat()
            ->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT);
```

This should set the default format to txt.

What smokey (and I suggested) was using a number format for each iteration.

```
$col = range('A','C');
$cell = '';
foreach($arr as $colIndex => $vals)
{
    $cell = $col[$colIndex];//the first array will be $col[0] === A
    foreach($vals as $row => $val)
    {
        $cell .= $row +1;//A.(0+1) -->A1
        $objPHPExcel->getCell($cell)
                     ->getNumberFormat()
                     ->setFormatCode(str_repeat('0', strlen($val)));
                     //for 001, this is str_repeat('0',3) or '000'
    }
}
```

This formats the cells accordingly, to add the correct amount of leading zeroes. If all else fails, this, is a fairly good way of setting the correct formats

Comment: `Try setting the cells to the text format` --- Please tell how to make this?

Comment: @OTARIKI: Well, my first snippet: `setFormatCode('@')` should do that, but you can also set the default style to text format (added the code for that in edit)

Comment: @OTARIKI: added code for the manual approach, too (setting the number format cell by cell, according to the string in `$arr`